# exam: How to make the solution box span the whole text width regardless the question level?

Tags: exam, width

I would like to make any solution box span the whole text width for any question/part/subpart/subsubpart.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{\underline{Answer:}}\par\noindent}
\printanswers

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question Some question.

  \begin{parts}
  \part some part
    \begin{solution}
    I need this solution box to span the whole text width.
    \end{solution}

    \begin{subparts}
        \subpart another question
        \begin{solution}
            I need this solution box to span the whole text width.
        \end{solution}
    \end{subparts}

  \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make the solution box as wide as the textwidth, you can enclose it in a `\fullwidth{<solution>}` command or use the `EnvFullwidth` environment. Details on this are discussed in the [`exam` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam):

> By  default,  the  solution  is  printed  in  a  box  whose  width  equals  that  of  the  text  ofthe  current  question  (or  part,  or  subpart,  or  subsubpart).   That  is,  the  indentation  at the  left  of  the  solution  equals  the  current  level  of  indentation.   You  can  change  this  byenclosing  the `solution`, `solutionorbox`, `solutionorlines`, `solutionordottedlines`,  or `solutionorgrid` environment in the argument of a `\fullwidth` or `\uplevel` command, or inside of a `EnvFullwidth` or `EnvUplevel` environment

The following MWE demonstrates the usage of the `\fullwidth` command as well as the `EnvFullwidth` environment:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{\underline{Answer:}}\par\noindent}
\printanswers


\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question The \textbf{fullwidth} approach

  \begin{parts}
  \part some part
   \fullwidth{ \begin{solution}
    I need this solution box to span the whole text width.
    \end{solution}}

    \begin{subparts}
        \subpart another question
      \fullwidth{   \begin{solution}
            I need this solution box to span the whole text width.
        \end{solution}}
    \end{subparts}

  \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\begin{questions}
\question The \textbf{EnvFullwidth} approach

  \begin{parts}
  \part some part
  \begin{EnvFullwidth}
     \begin{solution}
        I need this solution box to span the whole text width.
      \end{solution}
   \end{EnvFullwidth}

    \begin{subparts}
        \subpart another question
        \begin{EnvFullwidth}
          \begin{solution}
            I need this solution box to span the whole text width.
          \end{solution}
        \end{EnvFullwidth}
    \end{subparts}

  \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To apply the changes globally, you could define your own solutions environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{\underline{Answer:}}\par\noindent}
\printanswers


\newenvironment{widesolution}{\begin{EnvFullwidth}\begin{solution}}{\end{solution}\end{EnvFullwidth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question The \textbf{new environment} approach

  \begin{parts}
  \part some part
   \begin{widesolution}
    I need this solution box to span the whole text width.
    \end{widesolution}

    \begin{subparts}
        \subpart another question
     \begin{widesolution}
            I need this solution box to span the whole text width.
        \end{widesolution}
    \end{subparts}

  \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

---

To remove the vertical white space that is present in the two above shown examples when commenting out `\printanswers` we can use command `\ifprintanswers` as described in section 8.8 of the manual:

> **8.8    Changes  depending  on  whether  or  not  solutions  are  being printed**
>
> The  command `\ifprintanswers` is  provided  in  case  you  want  to  vary  what  appears  onthe exam in ways other than those provided by the solution environments (see section 8), the `\CorrectChoice` command in multiple choice environments (see section 5.5),  and the optional argument to the `\answerline` command (see section 7.7).  You use this command by typing:
>
> `\ifprintanswers`
>
> `Stuff to appear only when answers are being printed.`
>
> `\else`
>
> `Stuff to appear only when answers are not being printed.`
>
> `\fi`

Here is a short MWE that introduces a new environment `widesolution` that is full width only when `\printanswers` is used. Otherwise the `widesolutions` environment is equal to the `solutions` environment and therefore does not cause any additional white space if `\printanswers` is not used:

```
\documentclass[cancelspace]{exam}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{\underline{Answer:}}\par\noindent}
%\printanswers


\ifprintanswers
  \newenvironment{widesolution}{\begin{EnvFullwidth}\begin{solution}}{\end{solution}\end{EnvFullwidth}}
\else
    \newenvironment{widesolution}{\begin{solution}}{\end{solution}}
\fi



\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question The \textbf{new environment} approach

  \begin{parts}
  \part some part
   \begin{widesolution}
    I need this solution box to span the whole text width.
    \end{widesolution}

    \begin{subparts}
        \subpart another question
     \begin{widesolution}
            I need this solution box to span the whole text width.
        \end{widesolution}
    \end{subparts}

  \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to show me how to change it globally in the preamble?

Comment: @Diaa: You could define your own environment for this. I have edited my answer to include an example on how to define and use the new environment.

Comment: Many thanks for your edit. However, if you comment `\printanswers` in your new answer, you will get unneeded vertical space between `some part` and `another question` as shown [here](https://i.ibb.co/njPSnWh/Untitled.png).

Comment: @Diaa: That is unfortunately true, but also happens with the other options for wide solution boxes.

Comment: I am not knowledgable enough, but I think some conditions can be made by `etoolbox` to handle it.

Comment: @Diaa: The exam package offers the `\ifprintanswers` command that can be used as shown in my edited answer.

Comment: I completely overlooked it. Thanks for help.