# exam: Creating a solution environment whose width is set by an optional argument corresponding to the question level

Tags: indentation, mdframed, exam

Inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489236/2288), I would like to have a customized solution environment which accepts an optional argument. This argument can be either numeric or alphabetic, and its value corresponds to the question level whose width is desired to be set to the solution environment.

For example, suppose the question levels have some indices to be: `1` for questions, `2` for parts, `3` for subparts, and `4` for subsubparts. Then the new solution environment might be something like `\begin{solution}[2]` if I want the solution to span the whole line width of the part environment regardless of where I print this solution.

Finally, if I don't type the optional argument, I would like the width to be set by the parent question level.

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\renewenvironment{solution}
{\begingroup\par\parshape0%
\begin{mdframed}[skipabove=\baselineskip,
                 innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
                 innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
                 userdefinedwidth=\textwidth]
\textbf{Solution:}\enspace\ignorespaces}
{\end{mdframed}\par\endgroup}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question A question.
        \begin{parts}
            \part part
            \begin{solution}
                The long solution continues onto another page: \lipsum[1-8]
            \end{solution}
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}

    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want has been implemented as a package for clean reuse among several documents: the package is called `examwsolns` and can be found [here](https://github.com/frougon/examwsolns). Documentation is there too.

### Sample usage

Here is an `example.tex` file that shows how to use this package:

```latex
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
%\usepackage[replace-solution-env]{examwsolns}
\usepackage{examwsolns}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Also possible in the preamble:
% \examwsolnsSetup{replace-solution-env}
% \examwsolnsSetup{replace-solution-env=true}

% Default additional arguments to pass to the 'mdframed' environment
\examwsolnsSetMdFramedDefaultArgs{
  skipabove = \baselineskip,
  innertopmargin = \baselineskip,
  innerbottommargin = \baselineskip,
  userdefinedwidth = \linewidth
}

\begin{document}
Here is a full line:
\par\noindent\hrulefill

\begin{wsolution}
  Autodetected outer level.
\end{wsolution}

\begin{questions}
  \question A question.

    \begin{wsolution}
      Autodetected question level.
    \end{wsolution}

    \begin{parts}
       \part A part
         \begin{wsolution}[][innertopmargin = 2\baselineskip,
                             innerbottommargin = 2\baselineskip,
                             backgroundcolor=gray!40,
                             roundcorner=8pt]
           Autodetected part level.
         \end{wsolution}

         \begin{subparts}
            \subpart A subpart
              \begin{wsolution}
                Autodetected subpart level.
              \end{wsolution}

             \subpart
               \begin{subsubparts}
                 \subsubpart A subsubpart
                   \begin{wsolution}
                     Autodetected subsubpart level.
                   \end{wsolution}

                 \subsubpart Another subsubpart
                   \begin{wsolution}
                     Autodetected subsubpart level.
                   \end{wsolution}
               \end{subsubparts}
          \end{subparts}

       \part Other part
         \begin{wsolution}
           Autodetected part level.
         \end{wsolution}
    \end{parts}

  \question Other question
    \begin{wsolution}
      Autodetected question level.
    \end{wsolution}

    \begin{parts}
      \part A part
        \begin{wsolution}[1]
          Forced at level 1.
        \end{wsolution}

        \begin{wsolution}[2]
          Forced at level 2.
        \end{wsolution}

        \begin{wsolution}[3]
          Forced at level 3. \lipsum[2-8]
        \end{wsolution}

        \begin{wsolution}[4]
          Forced at level 4.

          \lipsum[9]\lipsum[10][1-2]
        \end{wsolution}

        {% \examwsolnsSetMdFramedPreText and \examwsolnsSetMdFramedPostText
         % respect TeX's grouping rules.
          \examwsolnsSetMdFramedPreText{\emph{Sample pre-text} $\langle$}%
          \examwsolnsSetMdFramedPostText{$\rangle$ \emph{Sample post-text}}%
        \begin{wsolution}[3]
          Forced at level 3.
        \end{wsolution}
        }

        \begin{wsolution}[2]
          Forced at level 2.
        \end{wsolution}
    \end{parts}

  \question Last question
    \begin{wsolution}[1]
      Forced at level 1.
    \end{wsolution}

    \begin{wsolution}[0]
      Forced at level 0.
    \end{wsolution}
\end{questions}

Here is a full line for comparison:
\par\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

### Output for the example.tex file given above

Page 1:

[image: Screenshot for page 1]

---

Page 2:

[image: Screenshot for page 2]

---

Page 3:

[image: Screenshot for page 3]

Comment: Many thanks. Your answer is really impressive and exhausting to just read. If you don't mind I would like one final tweak: could you please make the input of the optional argument of zero (i.e. `\begin{solution}[0]`) results in the width of `\textwidth` spanning all the space between the left and right margins as done by the MWE in my question?

Comment: Glad that you liked it (sometimes, people here ask questions, obtain responses that required a lot of work but no one reads them, not even the person who asked...). I've added handling of level 0 (“outer”). If you're still here, I may turn this into a package for clean reuse when you have several documents (probably the environment should have a different name [proposal?], with possibly an option to replace the existing `solution` environment; also, the optional arguments to `mdframed` should be parametrizable).

Comment: I always have to appreciate the time and effort anyone put in answering my questions with nothing in return.

Comment: For the environment name, it might be something like `widesolution` as suggested by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489152/2288).

Comment: Additionally, if you would like to check my other unanswered question that might need some sort of programming as well, you can find it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449001/2288).

Comment: I've updated my answer: 1) What I wrote [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489374/exam-creating-a-solution-environment-whose-width-is-set-by-an-optional-argument/489424#comment1236125_489424) is implemented. 2) The package is now hosted externally (see the answer). 3) The environment is called `wsolution`, where the `w` suggests this has something to do with width without being too precise. 4) It respects the `answers` option of the `exam` class (i.e., the `\ifprintanswers` conditional). 5) Pre-text and post-text inside the `mdframed` environment are customizable.

Comment: It would be great if you upload it to miktex/texlive to avoid manually downloading every update of it.

Comment: I believe it would be better to contact the maintainer of the `exam` class (ditto for your other question, by the way).

Comment: When trying to create an empty solution box with dots inside as instructed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448736/2288), the following `\begin{solution}[1]
   \centering
   \repeatit[3]{\myrepeat{130}{.}\\}
   \vspace*{\baselineskip}
  \end{solution}` doesn't have an escape vspace (i.e. `\vspace*{\baselineskip}`) as shown [here](https://ibb.co/R2n9pQJ) knowing that I loaded the package with `replace-solution-env` option.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it but got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7voF.png): no problem. You could try doing `{\centering ... \par}\vspace*{whatever}`, possibly followed by `\null` in case this doesn't work. I'd also suggest doing the dots with `\dotfill` and replacing the custom loop macros with something standard like `\pgffor`. No need for `\centering`, BTW. The following is much simpler and looks good to me: `\begin{wsolution}[1] \foreach \i in {1,...,3} {\noindent\dotfill\par} \end{wsolution}` → [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i0Zs.png). `\foreach` is defined in the `pgffor` package.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I am away from keyboard at the moment to try it. However, I would be highly grateful if you could make your comment as an answer to [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448736/2288).

Comment: Sorry, but too many things are unclear. In the other question, the dots have too appear in a question (from the `exam` point of view), but [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489374/exam-creating-a-solution-environment-whose-width-is-set-by-an-optional-argument/489424?noredirect=1#comment1279728_489424), your screenshot shows answer and there is “Answer:” in the box. This has influence on where and how the dots can/should be placed. In my screenshot, the dots starts on the same line as “Solution”. I like it this way, but this is not the case in the aforementioned link.

Comment: I have no idea if you want them my way or starting on the next line. It's important to know, especially considering the left and right margin requirements in your [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448736/2288) that you linked to here. Besides, you can't expect to control at the same time left & right margin plus length of dotted line: these 3 parameters are linked by a relation, they are not independent. So, things are a bit too unclear for me to answer. Hint: `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` could help for the margins.

Comment: I couldn't get the escape vertical space by `\vspace*`, but I got it by `\par\null\par` (is it because you wrote in the package `\tl_set:Nn \l_examwsolns_mdframed_post_text_tl { \unskip }`?). For the title `Answer`, I tweaked your package file by adding `\underline{\textbf { Answer \tl_to_str:n { : } }}
    \par\null\par`.

Comment: For the way the dots are printed, I hope to have control of their density/number in my way of printing the title individually on a single line.

Comment: Yes, `\unskip` is a likely culprit for eating your vertical skip (it doesn't distinguish between vertical and horizontal skips). You can get away with `\null` or `\kern 0pt`, but the normal way when you don't want the `\unskip` would be to do `\examwsolnsSetMdFramedPostText{}` before the `wsolution` env that needs the change. Use `\begingroup` or `{` before `\examwsolnsSetMdFramedPostText{}`, and `\endgroup` or `}` after the `wsolution` env(s) in order to limit the scope of the change. You don't need to modify my `.sty` to use the word “Answer”, ...

Comment: ... just do something like `\examwsolnsSetMdFramedPreText{\textbf{Answer:}\enspace \ignorespaces}`, with grouping as explained before if you want to limit the scope. Underlining is ugly. To control the dots, you can use `zref`s `\zdotfill` (probably the easiest way) or directly one of TeX's `\leaders`, `\cleaders` and `\xleaders` commands. For the latter, you can look at LaTeX's definition of `\dotfill`: `\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@` and write your own command with similar code but different values (don't forget `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`).

Comment: One more comment on the `\vspace*` problem you encountered: in order to counteract the `\unskip`, another easy way should be to use (for instance) `\par\kern 1cm` *instead* of the `\vspace*`. This should work because a `\kern` is not a skip. (Also, contrary to skips, kerns don't get discarded at beginning and end of {lines [for horizontal kerns]} {pages [for vertical kerns]}, but this should matter here unless `mdframed` is considering breaking the box across two pages).

Comment: I could push a change so that the pre-text and post-text can be set this way too: `\examwsolnsSetup{mdframed-pre-text={\textbf{Answer:}\enspace \ignorespaces}, mdframed-post-text={}}` (probably I should have done that from the beginning, as this would have removed the need for `\examwsolnsSetMdFramedPreText` and `\examwsolnsSetMdFramedPostText`) .

Comment: Hello :). I would like to know if it is possible to edit the package by providing a key for default level width. For example, is possible to have something like `\usepackage[default-width = outer]{examwsolns}`?

Comment: Hello. With `examwsolns` version 0.4, you can use the new `default-level` package option: `default-level=current|outer|question|part|subpart|subsubpart` (the initial value is `current`, which corresponds to the usual behavior).

Comment: Thanks for not giving up on this package :). I think you may find it useful to check [my relevant last question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/555627/2288). Thanks again for the response.