# Change leftmargin in itemize environment

Tags: indentation, itemize, leftmargin

I have some problems with the itemize environment. I want to change the symbol in an existing environment and for it to look good also change the indents. But there it only changes the indents of the first lines. And as fare as I know, I can not change the leftmargin from within itemize. I also don't want to close the itemize and open a new one because I sometimes want to change the symbol in the 3rd nested itemize layer.
I created following minimal example:

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\changeSymbol}{
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\rightarrow$}
\global\setlength{\itemindent}{-13pt}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent\lipsum[1]
  \begin{itemize}[itemindent=-20pt, topsep=0pt, label=-, itemsep=0pt]
  \global\setlength{\labelsep}{3pt}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \changeSymbol
    \item \lipsum[1]
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: the output]

Comment: Try  `\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=5em, itemindent=-20pt, topsep=0pt, label=-, itemsep=0pt]`

Comment: it only shifts the items further to the right. Also I couldn't change this in the command which is my main goal.

Comment: Making it work with enumitem may be more difficult than making it work with itemize.  I ran into some weird stuff working on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645742/in-the-exam-document-class-how-to-use-envuplevel-for-solution-that-spans-multip/645789#645789 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646551/adding-right-aligned-text-to-a-multi-line-list-item/646564?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#646564